# CRONTAB changing in script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

my task is to make a script which does server snapshots once a day for 7 days, then 
once for a week for 3 weeks moving to once for a month for 12 months. And the question is how can I change 
frequency of doing snapshots in CRONTAB without changing CRONTAB manually after 7 days then 1 month etc.

Comment: My guess would be to run a bash script everyday with cron. Your script will then check when was done the last snapshot, and decide whether to do the snapshot or not based on today's date

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is three separate entries in the cron table, including start and end time/date.  Coding this as a continuing time check from the start date is simply overkill, unless you have some need to restart this sequence every 3-12 months.